# How can we explain there is not exist $6$-digit self-descriptive number?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

a self-descriptive number is an integer $m$ that in a given base $b$ is $b$ digits long in which each digit $d$ at position n (the most significant digit being at position $0$ and the least significant at position $b - 1$) counts how many instances of digit $n$ are in $m$.

For example, in base $10$, the number $6210001000$ is self-descriptive because of the following reasons:

In base $10$, the number has $10$ digits, indicating its base;

It contains $6$ at position $0$, indicating that there are six $0$s in $6210001000;$

It contains $2$ at position $1$, indicating that there are two $1$s in $6210001000$;

It contains $1$ at position $2$, indicating that there is one $2$ in $6210001000$;

It contains $0$ at position $3$, indicating that there is no $3$ in $6210001000$;

It contains $0$ at position $4$, indicating that there is no $4$ in $6210001000$;

It contains $0$ at position $5$, indicating that there is no $5$ in $6210001000$;

It contains $1$ at position $6$, indicating that there is one $6$ in $6210001000$;

It contains $0$ at position $7$, indicating that there is no $7$ in $6210001000$;

It contains $0$ at position $8$, indicating that there is no $8$ in $6210001000$;

It contains $0$ at position $9$, indicating that there is no $9$ in $6210001000$.

There is not exist $6$-digit self-descriptive number. But I don't know how to explain it. Please give me some help.

Comment: Presumably, you can prove it by exhaustive search. There are just $900000$ numbers to try.

Comment: what is the source of this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly the sum of the digits is the total count of digits, so must equal 6. There are only a few ways to write 6 as the sum of 6 numbers (ignoring the order):

```
600000
510000
420000
411000
330000
321000
311100
222000
221100
211110
111111
```

In each case it is easy to check that it is not possible to order the digits to make it self-descriptive, because the count of digits does not match. For example, 411000 contains a 4, so some digit value has to occur 4 times, but none of them do.